# Невозможно вывести число

Tags: c#

В данном ниже коде в строке  `Console.WriteLine("{0}", U);` U (по словам компилятора) - локальная переменная, которой не присвоено значение, хотя она была инициализирована до этого. В чем причина ошибки и как ее исправить?

Полный код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double x, y, U;
    x = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    y = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (x >= -2 && x <= 2)
    {
        if (y >= -2 && y <= 2)
            U = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x * y));
    }
    else
        U = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x, 2) - Math.Pow(y, 3));
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", U);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: double x, y, U = 0; мб поможет :)

Comment: в вашем коде не во всех случаях переменная U будет проинициализирована. Например, если x=0, y=1000, что будет храниться в переменной U? Дайте ей сразу значение по умолчанию `double x, y, U = 0;` и живите спокойно

Answer (score 2):

Проблема вот в чём: когда вы объявляете переменную типа `int` ей присваиваеться значение `default` а точнее **0**. И когда вы это делаете неявно компилятор думает что вы упустили этот момент с объявлением переменной. Возникнет вопрос

***"А я же в условной конструкции присваиваю значение что ни так?"*** Я отвечу:

Когда вы делаете условную конструкцию вы используете булеву переменную как ни как и она может быть как и истиной (`true`) так и ложной (`false`). И если все же она вернет true тогда выполниться присваивание. А если нет?? Получается что переменная `U` так и останется не присвоенным явно значением? Так что сделайте просто так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double x, y, U;
    x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (x >= -2 && x <= 2)
    {
        if (y >= -2 && y <= 2)
            U = Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x * y));
        else
            U = 0; //if false U will be zero. 
    }
    else
        U = Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x, 2) - Math.Pow(y, 3));
    Console.WriteLine($"{U}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Да, также вы можете дать начальное значение переменной что бы в случае что блок с условием не сработает оно не измениться. Но я просто дал пояснение на примере

***А почему так??***

---

**SeeSharp**

Answer (score 0):

Задайте начальное значение переменной U,она в любом случае потом поменяет свое значение,а так там мусор мб какой-нибудь лежит:

```
double x, y, U = 0;
```

Comment: вы указали один из способов как полечить проблему, было бы здорово также указать в чем причина, почему эта ошибка вообще возникла у автора